# How to use table input with mark?

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I am using a sub-transformation **PARTNER_CONTACT_SUB** with 2 mapped fields like as below:

[image]

Then in my sub-transformation I execute an sql query in an input table **PARTNER_TYPE_SUB** like as below :

[image]
I'm use 2 mark from the INPUT SUB step.

But when I run the transformation, Pentaho responds this:

```
2021/02/01 14:27:48 - PARTNER CONTACT INPUT.0 - ERROR (version 9.0.0.0-423, build 9.0.0.0-423 from 2020-01-31 04.53.04 by buildguy) : Unexpected error
2021/02/01 14:27:48 - PARTNER CONTACT INPUT.0 - ERROR (version 9.0.0.0-423, build 9.0.0.0-423 from 2020-01-31 04.53.04 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
2021/02/01 14:27:48 - PARTNER CONTACT INPUT.0 - An error occurred executing SQL:
2021/02/01 14:27:48 - PARTNER CONTACT INPUT.0 - SELECT *, ? as partner_id 
2021/02/01 14:27:48 - PARTNER CONTACT INPUT.0 - FROM llx_socpeople 
2021/02/01 14:27:48 - PARTNER CONTACT INPUT.0 - where fk_soc = ?;
2021/02/01 14:27:48 - PARTNER CONTACT INPUT.0 - 
2021/02/01 14:27:48 - PARTNER CONTACT INPUT.0 - offending row : [societe_id Integer(9)], [nom ....
2021/02/01 14:27:48 - PARTNER CONTACT INPUT.0 - 
2021/02/01 14:27:48 - PARTNER CONTACT INPUT.0 - Error setting value #3 [String] on prepared statement
2021/02/01 14:27:48 - PARTNER CONTACT INPUT.0 - Parameter index out of range (3 > number of parameters, which is 2).
2021/02/01 14:27:48 - PARTNER CONTACT INPUT.0 - 
2021/02/01 14:27:48 - PARTNER CONTACT INPUT.0 -
```

Have you an idea ?

Thanks.

**My config :**

Pentaho 9.0 under Ubuntu 18

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduce your error.

Look 'PARTNER CONTACT SUB' step in 'partner' transformation. Here you need only 2 input field (rowid and res_partner_id) for 'PARTNER CONTACT SUB' step to  pass/ mapping to partner_contact transformation.  But 'PARTNER CONTACT SUB' step gets more than 2 field as an input. And produce the error.

You need to pass exact 2 field to 'PARTNER CONTACT SUB' step. Your 'Filtrage lignes' should return only 2 field.

Comment: thanks for you help But I do not know how to do, to return only 2 fields with step FILTER ROW (name 'Filtrage lignes')!

Comment: After step 'Filtrage Lignes'  -> you can use 'Select values' step and select only require 2 
 field  -> After that call step 'PARTNER CONTACT SUB'.    Still, if you can't manage this, please send me your ktr file, so that I can do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

thank you, I understood your solution
she looks perfect
I applied it
but it seems that the 2 arguments are not transmitted
[attached the ktr files](http://dl.free.fr/m5hRRFL7R)

Comment: Your 'select values' setp is ok for MAPPING (PARTNER CONTACT SUB) step.   Can you please confirm if your 'PARTNER TYPE SUB' step in transformation 'partner' get exact 2 field? If not then you need to use another 'select values' step here.

Comment: Apart from above, after run the transformation , can you please look in the preview for each step, if data transfer step by step properly. Specially , confirm 'select values' step get accurate field and values.